# How to traverse inside html tags using Javascript(jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML code as below

```
    <UL>
        <LI>
            <span> </span>        
            <a> Item 1</a>
            <UL>
               <LI>
                 <span> </span>        
                    <a> Item 1.1</a>
               </LI>
               <LI>
                 <span> </span>        
                    <a> Item 1.2</a>
                       <UL>
                        <LI>
                            <span> </span>        
                              <a> Item 1.2.1</a>
                        </LI>
                        <LI>
                            <span> </span>        
                              <a> Item 1.2.1</a>
                        </LI>
                        </ul>

               </LI>
            </UL>
         <LI>


    </UL>
```

I need a function to traverse each and every node using javascript(jquery). Item 1 has Item 1.1 and Item 1.2, and Item 1.2 has item 1.2.1 and 1.2.2 i want to traverse all the nodes, if its in the Item 1.1 node it has to check for whether it has child node, else it should go to item 1.2 and again check for whether it has child node, if it has children then it should traverse there and then if Item 1.3 present it should go there.

I hope you understood my problem, please bare me if i have not given proper problem statement, let me know if you have doubt.

Please some one can help me in this. Thanks

looks as follows:

[image: Please see here image for reference]

Comment: [Traverse a nested list with Javascript/jQuery and store in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18066860/traverse-a-nested-list-with-javascript-jquery-and-store-in-array)

Comment: First give ID or Class to your DOM elements so that you can start traversing

Comment: Are you looking for any output?

Comment: I'm looking for javascript function which can traverse through the each node.

Comment: According to my understanding , you need a function whose argument is item 1 node and return is its child list nodes. am i right ?

Comment: Please assume it has ID and class, then how can be javascript function code is written. looking for code as i'm new in javascript. @ YO YO

Comment: @ Vegeta, Yes you are right